# Chinese remainder theorem large modulo

Tags: prime-numbers, mathematica-online

I have the following modulo congruences:

```
x ≡ 0 (mod 2)
x ≡ 2 (mod 5)
x ≡ 21 (mod 41)
x ≡ 16793129237622992703097532489897447320171386 (mod 648250901^5)
```

I know, usually these types of problem can be solved using the ChineseRemainderTheorem, i.e:

```
ChineseRemainder[{0, 2}, {2, 5}, {21, 41}, {16793129237622992703097532489897447320171386, 648250901^5}]
```

But this does not work, so I wonder how to solve this in Mathematica?

The answer should be: $x = 45349414319770996556255505100816573064904553782$

Any ideas?

Comment: One idea would be to check documentation for `ChineseRemainderTheorem`. This is important for anyone, and all the more for those relatively inexperienced with the software (regardless of how well one knows the underlying math).

Answer (score 2):

Just a matter of synthax:

```
ChineseRemainder[
  {0, 2, 21,16793129237622992703097532489897447320171386}, 
  {2, 5, 41,    648250901^5}]

45349414319770996556255505100816573064904553782
```